# get the div parent element of a clicked element, in order to get the p class in the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<td id="monday">
<p class="outter">whatever here</p>
<p class="hidden" style="display:none">Some content I want to get</p>
</td>
```

Now the problem is - the td id will change (this is just one of many).

So what I'm trying to do, is when a user clicks on the .outter (it'll always be called outter), I want to find the td id, in order to then get access to the p class (which will always be 'hidden').

So I've tried this (document.body is to get round a dynamic loading problem I had):

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.outter', function() {
        var info = $(this).parent("td").$(".hidden").text();
        $("#rightBox").css("width", "200px");
        $("#rightBox").css("background", "#f0f0f0");
        $("#rightBox").empty();
        $("#rightBox").append(info);
    });
```

The issue I am having is in the very first line, getting the variable.
I want to say this particular .outter class, find it's parent, then find the hidden class within it. Then get the text within that hidden class. Then take that variable and dump it into #rightBox;

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `var info = $(this).parent("td").$(".hidden").text();` throws an error, you should use `find` or `children` method, as the target element is a next direct sibling of the clicked element, you can use `next` method, you don't need the ID of the parent element.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.outter', function() {
    // var info = $(this).closest('td').find('.hidden').text();
    var info = $(this).next('.hidden').text();
    $("#rightBox").css({"width": "200px", "background": "#f0f0f0"})
                  .html(info);
});
```

Note that you can also create a class and use `addClass` method instead of `css` method, this makes your code a little cleaner.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you for both options and the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.outter', function() {
    var info = $(this).next().text();
    $("#rightBox").css("width", "200px");
    $("#rightBox").css("background", "#f0f0f0");
    $("#rightBox").empty();
    $("#rightBox").append(info);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eMzcx/